# Finished with non-zero exit value 255

Tags: java, gradle, stanford-nlp

I'm using gradle to work with Stanford Phrasal.
When I use the command `gradle run` it fails with giving following error.

```
FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':run'.
> Process 'command '/usr/lib/jvm/oracle_jdk8/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 255

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

### **UPDATE**

When I tried `gradle run --stacktrace` I got following,

```
* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':run'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:64)

    ... 58 more
```

Comment: As suggested, try running with --info, --debug or --stacktrace to get more information. [There are a bunch of system.ext(-1) in Phrasal source](https://github.com/stanfordnlp/phrasal/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=System.exit%28-1%29). You're clearly hitting one of those.

Comment: I've updated the question

Comment: I find gradle particularly obtuse when debugging problems. Turn debug mode on: Try `gradle -X run`

Comment: @Bohemian it gives me a error. "Unknown command line option"

Comment: @Maan sorry about that - for `run` it's `-d` for debug. Try `gradle run -d` (I tested that and it works).

Comment: @Bohemian Yes it did work. But not a solution for my problem.

Answer (score 1):

The `run` task is added by the [application plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/application_plugin.html). It is of type JavaExec and just runs the class defined by `mainClassName` in build.gradle; which in your case is `edu.stanford.nlp.mt.Phrasal`

Now as @Bohemian said, your stack trace doesn't tell you much because all it is saying is that the java process returned `-1` which could have happened from one of several [code lines that exit with -1](https://github.com/stanfordnlp/phrasal/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=System.exit%28-1%29) in Phrasal.

adding `--debug` or `--info` to gradle commands aren't helping because they just change the log level of the gradle process, and not the separate java process being started by the JavaExec(run) task.

The simplest way to debug I reckon is run the `distZip` task, which creates a zip file of an executable jar and all required dependencies, unzip it, and run the jar with `java -jar` from the commandline. This should throw more helpful error messages about where the failure is occurring and you can go about fixing it from there.